# UIAlertView clickedButtonAtIndex method is not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

in .h file

```
@interface MenuViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

in .m file

```
@interface TACDIYMenuViewController ()

@end

@implementation TACDIYMenuViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self.imageViews count];
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(200, 100);
    return size;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    MenuViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MenuViewCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([indexPath row] < [self.imageViews count]) {
        cell.thumbnails.image = [self.imageViews objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    } else {
        cell.thumbnails.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"addMark.png"];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self doSomething];
}

- (void)doSomething{
    UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning"
                                                    message:@"Are you sure"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"NO"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"YES",nil];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if(buttonIndex == 0){
        NSLog(@"0");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"1");
    }
}

@end
```

However,the clickedButtonAtIndex is not called.How does it happen?
By the way, the view in MenuViewController is the subview of another class, which also has an UIAlertView and the clickedButtonAtIndex method. But it works well.

Comment: Did you include the protocol `UIAlertViewDelegate` to your class interface?

Comment: Yes, as I've mentioned above.

Comment: Remove () after doSomething.

Comment: and after that [self doSomething];

Comment: sorry, i type that by mistake

Comment: how did you call doSomething method?

Comment: did you call doSomething method?

Comment: of course I do in some other methods, but i didn't write those codes here.

Comment: write down the complete code if you really looking for help.

Comment: I copied the same code and checked.. Working neatly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may happen if the delegate object (instance of TACDIYMenuViewController in your case) is deallocated before the button on the AlertView is clicked.

Comment: Do you mean, let's say you call [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; after showing the alertview?

Comment: @Gel Fermis, yes, that would be one of possible scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
@interface MenuViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

With

```
@interface TACDIYMenuViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

Then it should work.

Comment: Although correctly pointed out, it should no matter whether you say you should implement  `UIAlertViewDelegate` or not. It will work without the `<UIAlertViewDelegate>` als well. As long a the method is there.

Answer (score -4):

please add this line before [alert show];
alert.delegate = Self;

Comment: The delegate is set in the constructor: `delegate:self`

Comment: actually he do that when init the AlertView.